# Show total of event per day (Full Calendar)

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to show total of event in a day inside my full calendar. Example if that day do not have any event, it will show 0. If got 1 event, it will show 1. It there anyway to do it?

I know need to use something like:

```
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) { 

        },
        eventAfterAllRender: function(view){

        }
```

but i dont know what to do inside the function. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "it will show 0". Where exactly should it show it? In each type of view your calendar provides you'd need a different place, since they all have different layouts. Once you've decided that, in eventAfterAllRender make an array with one entry for each day in the currently displayed date range, then run the clientEvents method to get all the events being displayed, loop through and them, for each one get the date(s) it covers and add 1 to the relevant array entry for each day covered by the event. Then finally loop through the array and write the value to the appropriate place in the UI.

Comment: @ADyson it will show sumwhere on`fc-day-top`. Do you have any example of code?

Comment: @ADyson it will show sumwhere on`fc-day-top`. Do you have any example of code?